# Selected option not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The "selected" property works just fine in my html, but for some reason it doesn´t in my javascript, and shows a 'blank' in default, without any option selected. What am I missing? The rest of the code works just fine, it´s just the "selected". I´ve also tried with selected="selected".
Thanks in advance.

```
$('#uConex')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="1">1</option>')
    .append('<option value="2" selected>2</option>')
    .append('<option value="3">3</option>')
    .append('<option value="4">4</option>')
    .val('whatever');
```

Comment: The issue is simply because you have no `option` with a `value` of `whatever`. If you change the code to `val('1')` - or remove `val()` completely - it works fine. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, I´m kinda new to javascript and didn´t realize.

Comment: No problem. I'd suggest deleting this question as it's not going to help any future visitors, and you'll get your points back :)

Comment: It says I can´t delete it: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#uConex` is a select field, which I think it is, you're setting `.val('whatever')`, which is trying to select the option with the value `whatever`.  Since whatever isn't a valid option, it can't actually select it, so it displays a blank box.  What are you trying to do with the `.val('whatever')`?

Comment: That value existed in the other select and I just didnt realize. Fixed now, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `val` parameter to value of your `option`

```
$('#uConex')
.find('option')
.remove()
.end()
.append('<option value="1">TEST1</option>')
.append('<option value="2" selected>TEST2</option>')
.append('<option value="3">TEST3</option>')
.append('<option value="4">TEST4</option>')
.val('2');
```

Comment: That value existed in the other select and I just didnt realize. Fixed now, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Add dynamics select options:

```
function addOption1(row){

            var $el = $(#idselect);

            var json = {

                "00:00": '00:00',
                "00:15": '00:15',
                "00:30": '00:30',
                "00:45": '00:45',

                };

            $el.empty(); // remove old options

            $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('To'));
            $.each(json, function(value, key) {
              $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
            });
            $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '99').text('Other sub function'));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#uConex')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="0">Select Value</option>')
    .append('<option value="1">1</option>')
    .append('<option value="2">2</option>')
    .append('<option value="3">3</option>')
    .append('<option value="4">4</option>')
    .val('0');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="uConex"></select>
```

Wrong selection **val('whatever')**  you need to select **val('0')**